# What do two stars mean in an Ant fileset tag?

Tags: ant, nant

```
<fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
```

what does two stars mean?

Answer (score 10):

AFAIK - ( I've used NAnt a few years ago ) - it means include all jar file in ${lib.dir} **and** subdirectories.

Comment: That is correct, based on http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.85/help/types/fileset.html.